# Django: How to show data record into Templates without render from Views?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a file called **header.html** and it is included by **base.html**. In header.html, I have a list of Categories, which are stored in the database. Now, I want to give that list to header.html. The problem is that no function is known to render the data into this file. So how do I do now. Heartfelt thanks!

Comment: Don't understand the question.  Parameters available to `base.html` should be available to `header.html` as well.

Comment: It means I do not need to send any array to header.html. But I still get the data from the database in header.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a template tag - specifically, an [inclusion tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags). This will render a template with a custom context, in your case the list of categories.

Comment: This solution seems to be satisfactory and easy to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make variables available in all templates without specifically passing them from a view you can use a [Template Context Processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors)

That will populate your RequestContext, available in the template.

I also suggest you look at [Template Inheritence](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) to build the relationships between templates instead of including one within the other.